# In my Cordova project, I want to trigger a function(search functionality) on iOS keyboard 'done' button click

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, keyboard-events

[image]

Is there anyway to solve this problem from native code.

Please ignore below two solutions:-

1. If(window.event.keyCode == 13) . This is not working. Pressing the "Done" key does not fire a keyCode event.
2. Keyboard will show and dismiss events. Since these event will call on screen touch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I analyzed, the good approach is to use Cordova keyboard plugin and listen for 'keyboardDidHide' event which will be fired on press of "Done" key. But ensure to deregister this event once you are done with the desired operations on click of "Done" key.

Sample code snippet as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidHide', function () {
    // logic which needs to be executed on click of "Done" key
    // Deregiter 'keyboardDidHide' event
});
```

More info on Cordova Keyboard Plugin is available on [official github page](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
      case 13: // enter button
          break;
      default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
   }
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

You can check all the char code for keys here : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-key-codes

Comment: Please read the question completely before answering. I already mentioned  clearly that this won't  work.